# I am unable to read any CSV file using Pandas on PyCharm, despite having installed pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
print(data.head())
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Shantanu
>   Shubham/PycharmProjects/dash/dashboard.py", line 6, in 
>       data = pd.read_csv('gapminder.csv')   File "C:\Users\Shantanu Shubham\PycharmProjects\dash\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 685, in parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)   File "C:\Users\Shantanu Shubham\PycharmProjects\dash\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 463, in _read
>       data = parser.read(nrows)   File "C:\Users\Shantanu Shubham\PycharmProjects\dash\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 1169, in read
>       df = DataFrame(col_dict, columns=columns, index=index)   File "C:\Users\Shantanu
>   Shubham\PycharmProjects\dash\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 411, in **init**
>       mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)   File "C:\Users\Shantanu
>   Shubham\PycharmProjects\dash\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",
>   line 257, in init_dict
>       return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)   File "C:\Users\Shantanu
>   Shubham\PycharmProjects\dash\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",
>   line 87, in arrays_to_mgr
>       return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)   File "C:\Users\Shantanu
>   Shubham\PycharmProjects\dash\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py",
>   line 1694, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
>       blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)   File "C:\Users\Shantanu
>   Shubham\PycharmProjects\dash\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py",
>   line 1752, in form_blocks
>       float_blocks = _multi_blockify(items_dict["FloatBlock"])   File "C:\Users\Shantanu
>   Shubham\PycharmProjects\dash\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py",
>   line 1846, in _multi_blockify
>       values, placement = _stack_arrays(list(tup_block), dtype)   File "C:\Users\Shantanu
>   Shubham\PycharmProjects\dash\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py",
>   line 1874, in _stack_arrays
>       stacked = np.empty(shape, dtype=dtype) MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (535, 79309) and data type float64
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

This means that the file you are reading is larger than the amount of RAM you have available. There are ways to split the file into "chunks" using generators which you can read up on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file you're importing has correct content/structure?

The error message 'Unable to allocate array with shape (535, 79309)' makes me think there's something wrong with the content of the file.

Here's how the shape function works:

```
from numpy import array
data = [[11, 22], [33, 44], [55, 66]]
data = array(data)
print(data.shape)
```

end you end up with:

```
(3, 2)
```

Now, the shape of the array you're trying to read is (535, 79309) - quite big, huh?